# How to split a query for conditions?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some code:

```
def search(name: str = None):
    q = db.query(City).join(Street)

    if name:
        q.filter(City.name==name)

    return q.all()
```

But it doesn't add a condition to my query and returns all the results. How in SQLAlchemy can I split the query into conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not adding it to the `q`. you have to assign it back to it, so, replace the your filter with:

```
q = q.filter(City.name==name)
```